How does the ODR interact with "unique" types that use a non-type template defaulted to a lambda expression?
If a class template uses a lambda a default template argument, every default usage of that class type will be a new type.
template <auto unique = [] {}>
struct UniqueStruct {};
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<UniqueStruct<>, UniqueStruct<>>);

However, in a single translation unit, both deriving and aliasing the class keeps that derivation / alias to a single type in all the modern compilers I tested.
using UniqueAlias = UniqueStruct<>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<UniqueAlias, UniqueAlias>);

struct UniqueDerived : UniqueStruct<> {};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<UniqueDerived, UniqueDerived>);

Will this behavior safely hold across TUs, or is there a possibility that different TUs will come up with a different lambda type for UniqueAlias / UniqueDerived? If so, would that make those types unsafe to use across multiple TUs, leaving UniqueStruct as the only safe type to use across TUs?

Alias don't create new types. So I don't think UniqueAlias will create different lambdas in different TUs.

Seems a lot like the problems you can run into using the COUNTER preprocessor symbol. In one TU it's fine, but you start mixing them and you can run into trouble.


is there a possibility that different TUs will come up with a different lambda type for UniqueAlias

A type alias don't create/generate new types. They only refer to(in other words are only an alias) for existing types. So for UniqueAlias the behavior will hold across different TUs also.
From type alias:


A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name. There is no difference between a type alias declaration and typedef declaration. This declaration may appear in block scope, class scope, or namespace scope.



It may not be creating a new type, but in my example it is "locking in" the lambda used by UniqueStruct<>, hence why multiple uses of UniqueStruct<> will be different but multiple uses of UniqueAlias will be the same (in the same TU). I'm wondering if there's any standard stances on if these "locked in" lambdas will be the same or different across TUs.
